# Java Question on how to cancel system input

Tags: java

I want to print last message when user inputs q but it gives an error.

---

### Language Translator Program

Please enter the input sentence (press q to exit):

Robin came to Montreal, Canada in 2009.

Robin stays in Montreal for 11 years. Montreal is in Canada.

Please enter the input sentence (press q to exit):

Lucy came to Berlin, Germany in 2000.

Lucy stay in Berlin for 20 years. Berlin is in Germany.

Please enter the numbers along operation (press q to exit):

q

Thanks for using translator program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MiniTranslator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String message ="";
        do {
            //Declaring scanner
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            //Printing greeting message

            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------\n" 
                                 +"\tLanguage Translator Program\n"
                                +"---------------------------------------------------------");

            System.out.println("Please enter the input sentence (press q to exit): \n");
            message = keyboard.nextLine();
            String[] arr = message.split("[ ,.]+",8);
            String name = arr[0];
            String city = arr[3];
            String country = arr[4];
            String year = arr[6];

            int noOfYears =2020 - (Integer.parseInt(year));

            System.out.println("\n" + name +" stay in " + city +" for " + noOfYears +" years. " 
                                + city +" is in " + country +".");
            System.exit('q');
            keyboard.close();
        }
        while(message!="q");
        if(message =="q") {
            System.out.println("Thanks for using translator program");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, (and this is probably the real reason for your error) you're closing the Scanner inside the loop which is a recipe for disaster. Close it outside of the loop after you're done using it

Comment: @Hovercraft Well, that's "one" problem :P

Comment: @mad, yeah, my bad. I'm on my phone and can't reopen it

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'd comment on all the "other" issues, but it's not very indicative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you have a number of immediate issues

`message!="q"` is not how you compare `String`s in Java, you should be using `!"q".equals(message)` instead (same with `==`, which would become `"q".equals(message)` for example)

But, your main problem is here ...

```
System.out.println("Please enter the input sentence (press q to exit): \n");
message = keyboard.nextLine();
String[] arr = message.split("[ ,.]+",8);
String name = arr[0];
String city = arr[3];
String country = arr[4];
String year = arr[6];

int noOfYears =2020 - (Integer.parseInt(year));
```

You've made an assumption on what `message` contains, instead of taking the time to ensure if contains what you think.

So, when `message` is `q`, your array will contain only one element, so as soon as you do `String city = arr[3];` you have an array index out of bounds issue.

A "simple" solution might be to check if `message` is equal to `q` before you split, but a better solution would be to check the number of elements in array...

```
if (arr.length == 7) {
    // Process the result
} else if (!"q".equals(message)) {
    // Invalid input
}
```

Also, as has been stated, you should create your `Scanner` once, outside of the loop and NOT close it - as you'd terminate the undying system input stream as well, which isn't pretty